# Avoiding repeated code execution on reused php component

Tags: php, javascript, web-applications

I am using a generic toolbar on multiple pages of my web application (using php include).

The toolbar houses some log in/log out functionality. Also, on load, it checks the log in status and updates its UI accordingly. The basic flow is that it starts by displaying a 'Checking log in' label, and then once the status is determined (using the Facebook javascript API), it updates the label to either 'logged in' or 'not logged in'. This is working fairly well.

My problem comes when the user navigates to a different page, which also includes the toolbar. The toolbar again goes through its on load status checks, meaning that on each navigation, it is updating the toolbar to 'checking sign in' until it has done its thing.

How might I avoid this? Keep in mind that the status check is partially useful - page navigation is a good time to re-check the status since I don't want to assume that the user is still logged in. But I would like to avoid constant label updates, or somehow hide them from the user.

Comment: It think it's hard to solve your problem without seeing any code. Can you show some? (I don't get the actual problem)

Comment: You could use a session variable and bypass the check if it is set.

Comment: Wouldn't that be a good thing. You should use sessions and if the user clears out the cache they should be logged out. Like @SomeSillyName said, you should run your check on your session.

Comment: I updated the question to mention that I am using the Facebook javascript API for login. Up till now I am not managing any sessions myself (I am using Parse for backend). Bit out of my depth I guess.

Comment: It sounds like in the long run you would be happiest if your navigation didn't reload the toolbar every time. If you structured your page to use Ajax for loading page content without loading the bar again, all will be well. That's not a trivial change, however.

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand right, you are using Ajax to see if the user is logged in?  Normally that would be handled with your PHP so that the page arrives pre-rendered with the toolbar saying the user is logged in or not.

If your javascript still needed to know whether the user is logged in, you can embed hidden JSON into the page that contains any needed user and login info.

Comment: I am using the Facebook javascript API for log in.